# Hangman Image concept

Tags: silverlight, flash, html, svg

I'm just realizing a little Web-Hangman where users can play the popular game.

Now I wondered, how I could design the image of the Hangman itself.

The page should not be reloaded in game.

I thought about those techniques:

- Images (changing via JS, much traffic)
- SVG-Graphics (once loaded, manipulated via JS)
- Flash (bad knowledge)
- Silverlight (bad knowledge)
- HTML 5 (bad reverse compatibility)

What would be the best practice? Are there any other ways to do so?

Thank you for your input!

**EDIT**: I am using PHP and JavaScript for programming of the rest of the website.

Comment: what language are you __actually__ using at the moment?

Comment: I am using PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: Flash would be my recommendation for a web based game.

Comment: Well, the game logics actually have to be in JavaScript/PHP, I was just wondering about the graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to create this with SVG or HTML5. Browsers are improving, mobile devices are rising.
SVG:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<svg>
    <polygon id="item1"/>
    <polyline id="item2"/>
</svg>
```

Then use JavaScript to toggle the items' visibility.

An alternative using HTML5 could involve canvas drawing, which seems easy as well. You could make a set of functions like this:

```
// JS
function draw1() { // Draw something
}
function draw2() { // Draw something
}
```

Combined with:

```
// JS
var errorCount = 0;
function onFalseGuess() {
    errorCount++;
    window["draw" + errorCount]();
}
```

Hope this is helpful :-) Good luck!

Comment: The Idea with visibility of the SVG Items seems to be the best solution. Is this also possible using DOM to add an element instead of marking it visible?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, but in a short test, it did not succeed, either.